# Stream or pseudo-stream h.264 on web browser

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, h.264, netcat

I'am actually streaming raw h.264 from a raspberry-pi with `raspivid`.

Then, I'm sending out the stream via TCP/IP on port 8080 using `netcat`:

```
raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -rot 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 15 -b 1000000 -o - | nc -lkv4 8080
```

Actually, this stream **is currently working** and **I'd like to read it on my webApp**.

I've tried to do so using the HTML5 `video` tag:

```
<video src="rtp://192.168.42.3:8080">
    Your browser does not support RTP streams.
</video>
```

or

```
<video src="rtsp://192.168.42.3:8080">
    Your browser does not support RTP streams.
</video>
```

but none of these are working. I can't even read the stream `rtp://192.168.42.3:8080` on my VLC player. Is there something I am missing here?

---

**Edit:**

I've actually tried `cvlc` and `GStreamer` and I'm still not able to connect to RTP either on a web browser or via VLC... I would love any insights of what to check next.

```
raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -rot 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 15 -b 1000000 -o - | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8080/}' :demux=h264


raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -rot 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 15 -b 1000000 -o - | \
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8080 \
                   caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" \
                   ! rtph264depay \
                   ! avdec_h264 \
                   ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Web browsers do not support rtp/rtsp. They also don’t support raw 264. You must put it in a container (like mp4) and serve it over http or web sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deliver video streams to web browsers as HLS, MPEG DASH, WebRTC using specific codecs (H264 baseline video with AAC audio for HLS/MPEG and Opus for WebRTC).

Comment: Thank you, but why can't VLC read the stream when connecting to *rtp://myip:8080* ?

Comment: Could be related to firewall or some error. 
You could check logs for errors and scan ports to make sure your command outputs something on that port.
After getting that sorted out you could use ffmpeg to convert rtsp to rtmp (that can be played in a flash player) or some other streaming server.
RTP/RTSP does not play in browser but you can output or convert to something that works.